# How to add new Div element on window click

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to achieve this behavior using vanilla javascript:

if I click on window anywhere on the page using:

```
window.addEventListener("click", function() {
   // code here
   // create div
   // append child to body
})
```

and after that I again want to click on the window I would like to add another (different) div but he problem is that If I have two

```
window.addEventListener
```

they will be invoke both at the same time and two divs will be added.
Is there a simple solution to this ?

behavior like this: click on the page add div.. click again add another different div.
Thank you

Comment: what happens if you have a third or fourth click?

Comment: Try creating a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example. What you've shown so far will work: unless you are **adding a new event listener for each element**, then yes, you will have multiple handlers being invoked at the same time.

Comment: It will add another div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just create one click eventhandler like you've posted before

> ```
> window.addEventListener("click", function() {
>   // code here
>   // create div
>   // append child to body
> })
> ```

This event handler will be fired upon every click of the window.
If you want to register a specific handler for an element use

```
document.getElementById('someidparameter').addEventListener("click, function() {
}
```

The crucial part here is the `document.getElementById()`

Then for the body of the click function go for this

```
var div = document.createElement('div'); // this will create an element
document.body.appendChild(div); // This will apend the div element to the body
```

your total code would look like this

```js
window.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div'); // this will create an element
  div.style.border = '1px solid #000'; // add this so you'll see a black border appearing
  document.body.appendChild(div); // This will apend the div element to the body

})
```

Comment: @aphex if this helped you and you've got your answer, feel free to mark :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new element to the body by calling appendChild() function of a HTML object. Depending where you want to add the new element.

For example:

```
var p = document.createElement('p'); // create new <p>
document.body.appendChild(p); // add it to the body
```